# Life span of a Light Bulb.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be the life span of one particular brand of light bulb and Y be the life span of another brand. Suppose that $X$ is $N(935, 7^2)$ and that $Y$ is $N(990, 11^2)$. If one of each brand is selected, find $P(X+50>Y)$.

I'm guessing this is a joint distribution problem. So the marginal pdfs of x and y would be the normal distribution formula of each. So to get the joint pdf you'd have to multiply both together, and take the double integral. It seems impossible to multiply the formulas together and then integrate it... it just seems like a mess. Am I approaching this problem at the wrong angle. Could really use some help, test coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\Pr[X + 50 > Y] = \Pr[Y - X < 50].$$  Then recall that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables, $Y - X$ is also a normal random variable with mean $\mu_{Y-X} = \mu_Y - \mu_X$ and variance $$\sigma_{Y-X}^2 = \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2.$$  Note that the variances add; the plus sign is **not** a typographical error.

---

A mechanical proof of the variance of a difference of independent random variables is: $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{Var}[Y - X] &= \operatorname{E}[(Y - X)^2] - \operatorname{E}[Y - X]^2 \\ &= \operatorname{E}[Y^2 - 2XY + X^2] - (\operatorname{E}[Y] - \operatorname{E}[X])^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[Y^2] - 2\operatorname{E}[XY] + \operatorname{E}[X^2] - (\operatorname{E}[Y]^2 - 2\operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y] + \operatorname{E}[X]^2) \\
&= \operatorname{E}[Y^2] - \operatorname{E}[Y]^2 + \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 + 2(\operatorname{E}[XY] - \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y]) \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[Y] + \operatorname{Var}[X] - 2\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]. \end{align*}$$  But if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y] = 0$:  they have zero covariance.

Comment: Wow, yeah that seems a lot more simple than what I was trying to do. Could you explain why the variances add instead of subtract (like the means did)? Thanks @heropup

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense. Doing all that I got Y-X ~ N(55,170). So P(Y-X<50) = P(Z < (50-55)/(squareroot(170)) = P(Z < -0.3834) = 0.3507... Does that seem like I did everything correct? Thanks again @heropup for that help.

Comment: @Luke Yes, that is correct.